# Wordpress: "get_the_tags" function with link to post in theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Am fairly new to Wordpress so sorry if a noob question but how do you insert tags from a blog post into your Wordpress theme with a link to the post?

like so:

```
<a href="{LinkToPost}">{TagName}</a>
```

I am currently displaying the tags in my theme like so:

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name . ' '; 
      }
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you need a link to the Post itself, you can use `get permalink()`. If you need a link to a Tag, then you can use `get_tag_link()`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link